# Splitting entities into pieces

Tags: sesam

How do I safely split an entity into multiple pieces? E.g. I have a document that looks like this:

```
{
  "_id": "Britney Spears",
  "hits": [
    {
      "title": "Crazy",
      "rating": 2
    },
    {
      "title": "Oops! I Did It Again",
      "rating": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

Into two entities that look like this:

```
[
    {
      "_id": "Britney Spears - Crazy",
      "artist": "Britney Spears",
      "title": "Crazy",
      "rating": 2
    },
    {
      "_id": "Britney Spears - Oops! I Did It Again",
      "artist": "Britney Spears",
      "title": "Oops! I Did It Again",
      "rating": 3
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

To process such as stream safely with deletion tracking you need to create two pipes. In the first pipe you build up the list of children entities (note that they require `_id`) using the `create-child` function. You must then store the output in an intermediate dataset and remember to set `track_children` to `true` on this dataset:

```
{
  "_id": "artists",
  "type": "pipe",
  "source": {
    "type": "embedded",
    "entities": [{
      "_id": "Britney Spears",
      "hits": [{
        "rating": 2,
        "title": "Crazy"
      }, {
        "rating": 3,
        "title": "Oops! I Did It Again"
      }]
    }]
  },
  "sink": {
    "type": "dataset",
    "dataset": "artists-with-hits",
    "track_children": true
  },
  "transform": {
    "type": "dtl",
    "rules": {
      "default": [
        ["copy", "_id"],
        ["create-child",
          ["apply", "song", "_S.hits"]
        ]
      ],
      "song": [
        ["add", "_id",
          ["concat", "_P._S._id", " - ", "_S.title"]
        ],
        ["add", "artist", "_P._S._id"],
        ["copy", "*"]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

In the next pipe you can then split up this entity:

```
{
  "_id": "hits",
  "type": "pipe",
  "source": {
    "type": "dataset",
    "dataset": "artists-with-hits"
  },
  "transform": {
    "type": "emit_children"
  }
}
```

If you try to do this in one pipe with multiple transforms, deletion tracking will not work.

This will give you the desired output in the `hits` dataset.